# VREF Output on STM32L0

Tags: c, stm32

I have an STM32L051 and want to drive an external DAC (SPI).

For that I would like to use the feature, mentioned in the [manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/21/bd/0f/bd/1c/88/40/f0/DM00108282.pdf/files/DM00108282.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00108282.pdf), to output the internal reference voltage to the PB1 pin of the STM32.

I use the STM32Cube HAL as a basis. However the examples of using the VREF are limited to internal use for ADCs and comparators.

If I understand correctly, I can use the CFGR3 register to both enable the VREF as well as connect it to the PB1. Using the Cube drivers, I can use the `HAL_SYSCFG_VREFINT_OutputSelect(SYSCFG_VREFINT_OUT_PB1)` function, but to enable it, I should use either `HAL_ADCEx_EnableVREFINT()` or `HAL_COMPEx_EnableVREFINT()`. The manual information on `SEL_VREF_OUT` indicates that `ENBUF_VREFINT_ADC` must be set.

Furthermore no mention is made about the configuration of the pin itself. Should I simply declare it as a DAC Pin? An ADC Pin?

Comment: have you checked: [STM32L051 and VREF out](https://community.st.com/thread/36821-stm32l051-and-vref-out) on community.st.com?

Comment: @Lanting I actually asked the same question on the community website, but it seems to be slowly approved by their moderators. And the exact link that you wrote did answer some confusion I had, but I just happened to find it in the manual as well. Still does not say much about the pin configuration.

Comment: Isn't it easier are more straightforward to set the registers instead of guessing which function does something. Two lines. And you are done.

Comment: @PeterJ_01, I actually tried that two lines, but unfortunately I could not see the reference voltage. So I was assuming there was more to it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

It is as simple as

```
if ( HALD_ADCEx_EnableVREFINT() != HAL_OK )
{
  Error_Handling();
}
HAL_SYSCFG_VREFINT_OutputSelect(SYSCFG_VREFINT_OUT_PB1);
```

And I can see the 1.22 V on the PB1 output.

It does not require further pin (GPIO) configuration.

---

#### Complications and justification for the question (can be skipped)

I had some issues with the board from out electronic dept. and thus switched to the STM32L053-Discovery board. The above solution did not work, and I kept seeing 0V on PB1 (or PB0).

I assumed that was due to some configuration missing. However, after some further tests, I actually found that on that Discovery board, both PB1 and PB0 are reserved for a sensor. By closing the SB23 bridge, I could use PB1 back to the GPIO, and thus see the reference voltage on the pin.